# Why must the Amazon S3 bucket name be the same as website name when hosting a static website

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket

I want to host a static website on S3, i.e. `example.com`. It requires a bucket name the same as `example.com`.

Then I found `example.com` had been occupied by other people.

So that's my question, why bucket name must be the same as the website name? For there are Route 53 to map the website to the bucket endpoints, it appears no necessary for this limitation.

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 19):

The brief answer is, "that's how Amazon designed it."

If the bucket name weren't the same as the domain name, how would S3 know which bucket to use to serve requests for a given domain?

You can't say "Route 53," because S3 was created before Route 53, and web site hosting in S3 works the same even if you aren't using Route 53 for DNS.

Similarly, it can't be a configuration option on the bucket, because that would just create a new series of problems -- if the previous owner of a domain still had their bucket configured with your domain, you'd have exactly the same problem as you do, now.

You can still host your site on S3, but with a mismatched bucket name, you need either a reverse proxy server in EC2 in the same region, to rewrite the host header in each request to match the bucket name, or, you can use CloudFront to accomplish a similar purpose, because the bucket name, then, does not need to match -- CloudFront will rewrite the Host header also.

Comment: I'll add that in order for the CloudFront approach to work _Cache Based on Selected Request Headers_ can't be set to _All_.

Comment: Uhh... the bucket name is in the URL... yet it still needs to be named the same as the domain which fowards to it? That doesn't make sense. S3 is providing a URL which looks like: `<bucketName>.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` and yet I can't redirect www.foo.com to it without getting a `Code: NoSuchBucket` error.

Comment: @papiro I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "it doesn't make sense."  That's how it works, though, and it seems like you may be conflating two different things -- the URL refers to what's in your browser's address bar, not the S3-assigned endpoint hostname you use as the DNS alias or CNAME record's target.  If you point the name www.example.com to a bucket using DNS then the bucket name must be exactly `www.example.com`.

Comment: The S3-assigned endpoint contains the bucket name, but even if it didn't, what's the technical reason you can't set a CNAME forward from foo.com to joeschmoe.s3.amazon.com (or whatever) without AWS getting confused? The forward must be happening, and then AWS decides to use the original host to identify the bucket, instead of using the actual url it has assigned. Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't dns route the request to the s3-assigned url and instead of aws looking at the bucket associated with it, it tries to find the bucket with the same name as the origin if it doesn't match.

Comment: The technical reason is that original hostname (i.e. the one typed into the browser's address bar) is the only authority information available in an HTTP request. The DNS resolution chain isn't preserved, so a web server has no idea how you got to it, through a cascade of CNAMEs, etc. If you configure `www.example.com CNAME www.google.com` and then go to `www.example.com` in your web browser, you will connect to a Google-owned web server but you **will not** see the content for www.google.com.  You'll get an error from the Google server, since it has nothing to show you for `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 4):

There's a pretty simple reason for this: by the time Amazon gets the request from your browser, the main information available is the domain in the URL, which isn't enough to figure it out.

Suppose your site is `example.com`, but that bucket name is taken, so you make the bucket `my-example`. Then you'll have an URL something like `http://my-example.s3-website.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`. That will work just fine in your browser, because it gets resolved to some AWS web server, which looks at the [`Host` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host), pulls out your bucket name, and grabs your bucket content.

Now suppose you add something to Route53 to make `example.com` work. You can either add A records, which let your browser turn `example.com` directly into an IP address for some AWS S3 webserver. Or you can put in a CNAME, which points from example.com to the full my-example hostname. Either way, your browser's going to look up an IP address, contact an Amazon webserver, and send a `Host` header that just says `example.com`. So if that isn't the bucket name, it doesn't know what to do.

Admittedly, it could go an extra step. After all, you *told* it the hostname when you set up the bucket for serving websites. So at first thought, it seems like it would be nice if it used that as well. However, that won't really solve your problem either, because whoever set up the `example.com` bucket could well have set it up for hosting.

It seems like the best way to work around this is Cloudfront, which can associate domain names with arbitrary buckets.

Comment: "Either way, your browser's going to look up an IP address, contact an Amazon webserver, and send a Host header that just says example.com" - So, if the webserver actually had a bucket named - example.com which is owned and setup for hosting by someone else, would the user get back website hosted by example.com ? Or AWS checks the host header against FQDN? Of course, I am referring to your specific example scenario

Comment: Good question, Abhishek. The only thing in the HTTP request is the `Host` header, so if the person types "example.com" into their browser, that's what Amazon will serve, even if there's a CNAME under the hood. Try using Wireshark to capture some HTTP requests and you'll see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Thanks @William Pietri. & I think this is the same behavior you were explaining in "However, that won't really solve your problem either, because ...." - correct?

Answer (score -2):

I think is the way AWS have designed this and that's it : [Check this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started.html#getting-started-create-s3-website-bucket)

I have this done for my company's website and it works great!

**Create an S3 bucket and configure it to host a website**

> Amazon S3 lets you store and retrieve your data from anywhere on the
>   internet. To organize your data, you create buckets and upload your
>   data to the buckets by using the AWS Management Console. You can use
>   S3 to host a static website in a bucket. The following procedure
>   explains how to create a bucket and configure it for website hosting.

**To create an S3 bucket and configure it to host a website**

- Open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.
- Choose Create bucket.
- Enter the following values:

  - Bucket name - Enter the name of your domain, such as example.com.
  - Region - Choose the region closest to most of your users.

    - Make note of the region that you choose; you'll need this information later in the process.

      - Choose Next.
      - On the Configure options page, choose Next to accept the default values.
      - On the Set permissions page, uncheck the Block all public access check box, and choose Next.

**Note**
The console displays a message about public access to the bucket. Later in this procedure, you add a bucket policy that limits access to the bucket.

- On the Review page, choose Create bucket.
- On the list of S3 buckets, choose the name of the bucket that you just created.
- Choose the Properties tab.
- Choose Static website hosting.
- Choose Use this bucket to host a website.
- For Index document, enter the name of the file that contains the main page for your website.

**Note**
You'll create an HTML file and upload it to your bucket later in the process.

- Choose Save.
- Choose the Permissions tab.
- Choose Bucket policy.

Copy the following bucket policy and paste it into a text editor. This policy grants everyone on the internet `("Principal":"*")` permission to get the files `("Action":["s3:GetObject"])` in the S3 bucket that is associated with your domain name `("arn:aws:s3:::your-domain-name/*")`:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[{
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":[
         "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource":[
         "arn:aws:s3:::your-domain-name/*"
      ]
    }]
}
```

- In the bucket policy, replace the value your-domain-name with the name of your domain, such as example.com. This value must match the name of the bucket.
- Choose Save.

**Create another S3 Bucket**, **for www.your-domain-name**

In the preceding procedure, you created a bucket for your domain name, such as example.com. This allows your users to access your website by using your domain name, such as example.com.

If you also want your users to be able to use www.your-domain-name, such as www.example.com, to access your sample website, you create a second S3 bucket. You then configure the second bucket to route traffic to the first bucket.

**Note**
Websites typically redirect your-domain-name to www.your-domain-name, for example, from example.com to www.example.com. Because of the way S3 works, you must set up the redirection in the opposite direction, from www.example.com to example.com.

**To create an S3 bucket for www.your-domain-name**

- Choose Create bucket.
- Enter the following values:

  - Bucket name - Enter www.your-domain-name. For example, if you registered the domain name example.com, enter www.example.com.
  - Region -Choose the same region that you created the first bucket in.
- Choose Next.
- On the Configure options page, choose Next to accept the default values.
- On the Set permissions page, choose Next to accept the default values.
- On the Review page, choose Create bucket.
- n the list of S3 buckets, choose the name of the bucket that you just created.
- Choose the Properties tab.
- Choose Static website hosting.
- Choose Redirect requests.

  - Enter the following values:

    - Target bucket or domain
    - Enter the name of the bucket that you want to redirect requests to. This is the name of the bucket that you created in the procedure To create an S3 bucket and configure it to host a website.
    - Protocol - Enter http. You're redirecting requests to an S3 bucket that is configured as a website endpoint, and Amazon S3 doesn't support HTTPS connections for website endpoints.
- Choose Save.