# Create AWS Cloud Map DNS alias for an S3 static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-route53, aws-cloudmap

[Route 53 can route traffic to an S3 bucket with static web hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html#routing-to-s3-bucket-configuring), but [you can't manually add records to a Route 53 namespace managed by Cloud Map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58751054/150884).

So how should Cloud Map be configured to route traffic from `mys3website.private-namespace` to `mybucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`?  And how can this be written in Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done because [S3 relies on the HTTP Host header to determine the bucket name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883888/why-amazon-s3-bucket-name-must-be-the-same-as-website-name-when-hosting-a-static).  So a DNS CNAME record won't help in renaming the bucket.